# How to get system date update notification?

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming. I just want to know if there's any function for getting notification whenever system date is updated. I just want a system date update notification and a direct function to do it.

Comment: _Welcome to_ **StackOverflow**. And please try to write precise titles.

Answer (score 0):

what do you exactly want.. the system date is constantly updated. 
are u updating the system date and looking for confirmation if it is updated or not?

if so then compare the updated time and see if the difference is of more than a second